# how to update user data provided by AuthState.authenticated

Tags: flutter, authentication, state, bloc

I am wondering how to update the user data if you store the user in an authentication bloc state.

```dart
 @override
  Stream<AuthState> mapEventToState(
    AuthEvent event,
  ) async* {
    yield* event.map(
      authCheckRequested: (e) async* {
        final userOption = await _authFacade.getSignedInUser();
        yield userOption.fold(
              () => const AuthState.unauthenticated(),
              (user) => AuthState.authenticated(user),
        );
      },
      signedOut: (e) async* {
        await _authFacade.signOut();
        yield const AuthState.unauthenticated();
      },
    );
  }
```

If the user is authenticated and updates any of its data, I would like to call the `authBloc` again with event `AuthCheckRequested`. However, since the state has not changed, it would not update the `user` (not yield the same state again). So I could yield an intermittent state. But this does not feel right to have any other state than authenticated in between. And worse, I would have to pause code execution for 50 to 100ms, because otherwise BLoC will ignore the sequence of state A -> intermittent state -> state A (what I learned the hard way).

Any ideas how to approach this?